# combine two fields for slug in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

I have used [Slugged](https://github.com/Sutto/slugged) gem, and have it working fine in standard mode which is slugged on one name field.

Next thing I want to do is to combine two fields into the slug, example I have a link model that is linked to two item records. I want the link slug to have the names of both the items. Example /link/item1name-and-item2name

Answer (score 1):

```
is_sluggable :full_name

def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `:convertor` option and pass a method name or block 
something like:

```
is_sluggable :convertor => :my_method

def my_method
 "#{item1.name} and #{item2.name}"
end
```